# How to stay logged in after refreshing the page if I have token stored in local storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

How to stay logged in after refreshing the page if I have token stored in local storage.

-or-

How to after receiving token from server(due to successful login), redirect to `www.mypage.com/welcome` page, but server will send to me this page only if I identify yourself as verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do it via local storage. That's why cookies exist.

Answer (score 0):

import this `import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt'` and add this simple function
`loggedIn() { return tokenNotExpired }`, some function of rxjs was deprecated in angular 6, so I use rxjs-compat for backward compatibility. It solve the issue.
Also, check this https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're just using vanilla JS here.

You can check if an item is in local storage by using the `localStorage.getItem('yourItem')` method and an `if` statement, which would look something like:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('yourItem') === null) {
  // code to execute if the item isn't in local storage
} else {
  // code to execute if the item is in local storage
  window.location = //full url to redirect to
```

`window.location` can be used to send the user to another URL inside the else block if they have your item in their local storage.